# Swift Init Optional Array in Struct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I can do an element with optinal like below but I dont know how create optional Array in Struct.

```
struct HomeElement {
     var title:String!
     var description:String?
     var body:String!

     init(title:String!,description:String,body:String!) {
           self.title = title
           self.description = description
           self.body = body
      }
}
```

I get an exception below code that nil for UIImage Array. How can I do when the Images input comes as nil.

```
struct HomeElement {
     var title:String!
     var description:String?
     var body:String!
     var images = [UIImage]()

     init(title:String!,description:String,body:String!,images:[UIImage]) {
           self.title = title
           self.description = description
           self.body = body
           self.images = images
      }
}
```

Comment: You can declare you `images` `array` as `var images : [UIImage]?`

Comment: Thanks @iPeter .

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: All the `var`, all the `!`... this is guaranteed to blow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the variable as Optional.

```
struct HomeElement {
    var title:String!
    var description:String?
    var body:String!
    var images: [UIImage]?

    init(title:String!,description:String,body:String!,images:[UIImage]?) {
           self.title = title
           self.description = description
           self.body = body
           self.images = images
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @regina_fallangi.